# How to make HTTP POST/GET in a c++ metro app?

Tags: c++, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a some web services that my app needs to communicate with by sending json with REST over HTTP POST/GET. The only way I can see to do this is with the iXMLHTTPRequest2 framework but geeze oh man is it uglier than I want to deal with.

Is this the only option I have to look at with c++?

Would this be easier with c#? I know most of the things are the same across the languages, but if c# has a better way to do this, I'd be willing to make the jump.

Answer (score 1):

You should also look into [Project Casablanca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/casablanca.aspx) - it's a fully native C++ library that also is adapted for use with Metro apps (I believe it wraps IXHR2).  I've been using it to perform http REST calls and to parse JSON very successfully.

Comment: Thanks, I actually did look at Casablanca but couldn't get it to build for me. Maybe it's been updated by now. I ended up directly using iXMLHTTPRequest2.

Answer (score 0):

That's the interface you have to use in C++.  It is more difficult than in C#.  Given that, there is a [good sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/HttpClient-sample-55700664) that will make using that interface a bit more bearable.

Comment: That's what I figured. I bit the bullet and made use of the MS sample (the same one you provided a link to). You can semi-easily port their httpRequest class to meet your needs.